# Does Linuxptp support IEEE802.1AS 2020 standard?

Tags: linux, networking, time

Could anyone please tell me if the linuxptp is planning to release IEEE802.1AS-2020 support for linuxptp stack
Is there any plan/timeline for this release?
If already released can anyone please provide me the information about the same

or is there any opensource ptp stack which support IEEE802.1AS-2020 support?

Regards,
Sunil Kumar

Comment: Why don't you ask the linuxptp maintainers? Unless someone reading your question here happens to be one of them, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no plan for supporting IEEE802.1AS-2020 by LinuxPTP maintainers and There is an Alternative for linuxptp which has IEEE802.1AS-2020 support it is provided by Company called Excelfore.
Currently, NXP's GenAVB_TSN support IEEE802.1AS-2020
https://github.com/NXP/GenAVB_TSN

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://tsn.readthedocs.io/timesync.html#avnu-automotive-profile) to "TSN Documentation Project for Linux*"

Describing:
Linux PTP also supports the Automotive Profile. To run ptp4l in that mode, the command-line is the same as presented in Synchronizing the PHC but with a different configuration file.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31861015)